# Who designed EV3RSTORM?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, history

I wonder, who designed EV3RSTORM? I have searched on Google but no results.

Answer (score 2):

Brickset identifies JØRN THOMSEN as the designer of the 31313 set:

https://brickset.com/sets/31313-1/Mindstorms-EV3

Although I'm also inclined to believe that probably a group of people came up with the various initial robots.

Answer (score 0):

I think that actually the five main robots were made by a *group of people*.

On [this](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/themes/mindstorms/buildarobot) page, it tells who designed the fan robots, but it doesn't say so for the 5 main robots, which include EV3RSTORM.

To quote from [this site](http://hackeducation.com/2015/04/10/mindstorms#):

> Like the early robot turtles, these programmable Lego constructions were still tethered to a computer with wires. So Seymour Papert wondered if it would be possible to create a Lego brick that could serve as the computer – a fully programmable brick.
>
> A working prototype was built by the Media Lab in 1987, but it wasn’t until a decade later that Lego trademarked Mindstorms – a nod to Papert’s 1980 book Mindstorms: Children, Computers, and Powerful Ideas – and brought the programmable brick to market.

It says it was made by a group called Media Lab. It doesn't mention any specific names though, so once again it's likely a group of people... who probably designed *all* of the EV3, including the brick itself and all 5 main models.

<sup>oh I forgot, Papert was one of the people in the media lab apparently</sup>

Comment: A group of 12 people: the [LMEP](http://botbench.com/blog/2013/01/07/lego-mindstorms-ev3-announced/), or [12 monkeys](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/how-lego-is-constructing-the-next-generation-of-engineers-37671528/)...